# find if two consecutive lines are different and where

Tags: bash, awk, sed, echo

How to find the difference and point of difference between two consecutive lines of a fixed width file ?

sample file:

```
cat test.txt
1111111111111111122211111111111111
1111111111111111132211111111111111
```

output :

it should inform user that there is difference between two lines and the position of difference is at :18th character.(as in above example)

It would be really helpful if it could list all the positions in case of multiple variations.For example:

```
11111111111111111211113111
11111111111111111211114111
```

Here is should say : difference spotted in 18th and 26th characters.

I was trying things in following lines, but seems lost.

```
while read line
do

echo $line |sed 's/./ &/g' |xargs -n1 #NOt able to apply diff (stupid try)

done <test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an empty field separator to make each character a field in `awk` and compare entries of every even record with odd numbered record:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="" } NR%2 {
  split($0, a)
  next
}
{
   print "line # ", NR
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($i != a[i])
         print "difference spotted in position:", i
}' test.txt

line #  2
difference spotted in position: 18
line #  4
difference spotted in position: 18
difference spotted in position: 23
```

Where input data is:

```
cat test.txt

1111111111111111122211111111111111
1111111111111111132211111111111111
11111111111111111211113111
11111111111111111311114111
```

**PS:** It will only work on `awk` versions that split records into chars when `FS` is null, eg GNU awk, OSX awk etc.

Comment: thanks , I modified your script as per my need(To print the exact difference as well) .Working well!!

Comment: you can replace `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i] = $i` with `split($0,a)`

Comment: 2nd block where for loop is, only executes when `NR%2==0` is true

Comment: You should mention it'll only work in awks that split records into chars when FS is NULL (non-POSIX behavior, gawk supports it idk about other awks) and idk if it can happen or not but it wouldnt find the difference if line 1 was longer than line 2.

Comment: I tested it on gnu-awk as well on my OSX awk and it worked fine on both.

Comment: That's why I didn't say gawk-specific because I thought it might behave that way in some other awks too but it is undefined behavior wrt POSIX. From [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html): `If FS is a null string, the behavior is unspecified.`

Comment: Yes I do agree woth you that POSIX awk might behave differently. I just couldn't get hold of pure POSIX `awk`.

Comment: FWIW I'd just do what you did but just say it only works on awks that split records into chars when FS is null, eg GNU awk (and, apparently, OSX awk). Obviously with gawk you can always use `--posix` but that doesn't guarantee that undefined behavior will or won't work any given way in any given POSIX awk since the implementer can choose to have their awk do whatever they like and it'd still be POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
$ echo '11131111111111111211113111
11111111111111111211114111' \
| perl -le '$d = <> ^ <>;
             print pos $d while $d =~ /[^\0]/g'
4
23
```

It XORs the two input strings and reports all positions where the result isn't the null byte, i.e. where the strings were different.

Comment: It should also be pretty fast for long input strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ curr = $0 }
(NR%2)==0 {
    currLgth = length(curr)
    prevLgth = length(prev)
    maxLgth = (currLgth > prevLgth ? currLgth : prevLgth)
    print "Comparing:"
    print prev
    print curr
    for (i=1; i<=maxLgth; i++) {
        prevChar = substr(prev,i,1)
        currChar = substr(curr,i,1)
        if ( prevChar != currChar ) {
            printf "Difference: char %d line %d = \"%s\", line %d = \"%s\"\n", i, NR-1, prevChar, NR, currChar
        }
    }
    print ""
}
{ prev = curr }
```

.

```
$ cat file
1111111111111111122211111111111111
1111111111111111132211111111111111
11111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Comparing:
1111111111111111122211111111111111
1111111111111111132211111111111111
Difference: char 18 line 1 = "2", line 2 = "3"

Comparing:
11111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111
Difference: char 24 line 3 = "1", line 4 = ""
Difference: char 25 line 3 = "1", line 4 = ""
Difference: char 26 line 3 = "1", line 4 = ""
```